# how to send product csv to custom email

Tags: product, csv

Hi i want to send product import csv to some custom email address. How I achieve this?

can you please give me some idea about this? it's like automatically send email to some custom email id

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and unlikely to be answered. If you are trying to send a CSV to someone, just send it? Attach it?

If you mean programmatically after an import then I think you need to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: Yes i want to import programatically and send to custom mail